# Import file.po into odoo for translation of fields from English to French

Tags: odoo, translation, odoo-8, erp, po

I am trying to import a file.po into Odoo to change some fields. Knowing that I have original fields in English and I
 want to translate some of them into French.

1. I export the file.po
2. I edit it with poEdit
3. I save the changes
4. I try to import it and it doesn't work at all, I can't update the po on Odoo.

I tried to change directly the fields on Odoo and it works but once you want to export the po file it's not synchronised and Odoo starts showing errors.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What are the errors? Could you provide us the file content or just a part of it?

Comment: what do you mean by the file content ?

Comment: it's just a normal po file with fields in source language and their translation, when i want to import the po file into Français/ French Odoo tells me that the language already exists. and i already know that but i want to update it

Comment: The PO comments are the interesting parts i'd like to see. Odoo is using them to create or update its translations.

Comment: Yes i know that and i've been looking in the files for these modules mentionned in the comments but i can't find them. i've read in a forum that you don't have to go manually and look for these files but you can just simply upload the file.po but it doesnt work on my Odoo. have u ever tried to upload the file . po directly ?

Comment: Actually, no, i've never tried to update translations with a .po file directly. Instead i wrote my custom module and translated terms in its .po. Translations are a mess in Odoo :-/

Comment: is it possible that i have Odoo running on my computer but i dont have access to its files po ? because i really can't find them at all on the computer directly.

Comment: On which OS are you on? Typically Odoo is installed as python dist-package. Your "imported" file will be processed and usually transformed to database entries of model `ir.translation`.

Comment: am on Windows 7 Entreprise

Comment: Sorry i can't help with Windows, never developed on a Windows machine.

Comment: As far I know, the existing translation terms can't be updated via export-import. You can change directly in menu Settings >> Application Terms >> Tranlsated Terms. Export-import method only works on terms which doesn't exist before exporting. Hope it helps you.